# JSON.parse error when in text is present \' or \"

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

In PHP I use `mysql_real_escape_string` that transforms symbol ``' and `"` to `\'` and `\"`

After, I extract data from MySQL and use it in JavaScript as JSON.

For example, the `b'` is transformed `to b\'` , and in JavaScript I have these errors:

```
var a='{"a":"b\'"}';
var b=JSON.parse(a);
alert(b.a);

var a='{"a":"b\""}';
var b=JSON.parse(a);
alert(b.a);

/*
Exception: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 9 of the JSON data
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to include the quote in the JSON String, add an addition `\`.

> Example

```js
var a = '{"a":"b\'"}';
var b = JSON.parse(a);
alert(b.a);

var a = '{"a":"b\\""}';
var b = JSON.parse(a);
alert(b.a);
```

Comment: But this not work  
var a = '{"a":"b\\'"}';
var b = JSON.parse(a);
alert(b.a);
/*
Exception: unterminated string literal
@Scratchpad/1:1
*/

Comment: Work this
var a = '{"a":"b\'"}';

Comment: @Iahim Sorry, but `'{"a":"b\'"}'` is the only way that case can be written. You _cannot_ use `'{"a":"b\'"}'`

Comment: agreed with u, if u still need only this is the solution, alert(b.a+'"'); @Iahim

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra quote from this line `var a='{"a":"b\""}';`

**Modified Code:**

```
var a='{"a":"b\"}';
var b=JSON.parse(a);
alert(b.a);
```

Comment: I need the extra  quote. I don't need \. It is added by Php.

Comment: @Iahim: this will not return u backslashes, check in console.log(b); result is  Object { a="b"}

Comment: This will return onl b, but i need b' or b"

Comment: If someone for example add a commet that contain ' or " then i parse with json this comment i have error and comment not appear.

Comment: @Iahim: as other friend, its not possible, only one solution, hard code the quote like alert(b.a+'"');

Comment: This also work 
var a = '{"a":"b\\""}';
var b = JSON.parse(a);
alert(b.a);

Comment: And this not work in my script but in console work
var a = '{"a":"b\'"}';
var b = JSON.parse(a);
alert(b.a);

Comment: u will get the SyntaxError: unterminated string literal in this solution @Iahim  why not like that alert(b.a+'"');

Comment: alert(b.a+'"'); i think not
How can i use it whe i receive data from mysql in this form \' or \".
And perform for cicle to make html. I need to find ' or " in string and remove it with ""?

Answer (score 0):

```
var a='{"a":"b\'"}';  //or you can use "{\"a\":\"b'\"}";
var b=JSON.parse(a);
alert(b.a);
```

This works because the value stored in variable `a` is `{"a":"b'"}`

```
var a='{"a":"b\\""}';    //or you can use "{\"a\":\"b\\\"\"}";
var b=JSON.parse(a);
alert(b.a);
```

For this case the value stored in variable `a` is `{"a":"b\""}`

You can try to construct the string that the JSON should look like by constructing the object and stringify it like so:

```
var a = { "a" : "b'" };
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: I delete or replace in php characters (5-10 characters) that user enter and make me problems like #10 #13 (like in Delphi), eof, \, " and other that mysql escape, and after select, delete, insert or update the mysql table.
Can I use it in this mode?? Or is not good?

Answer (score 0):

After you extract data from MySQL, use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to strip the extra backslashes. And then encode the data as JSON.

Comment: Use stripslashes 100 times per one page for each cell from DB (<? echo stripslashes($row['x']); ?>) or is possible to stripslashes like

    $res=myslq_query ... $res=stripslashes($res);

? 
I think is easy to not add slashes to DB by delete characters that produced it then insert or update data (in max 10 places in code) : a1,00,carredge,end line, and other (it is max 5-10 characters)